# Device Administration Problem after RESTART

Tags: android, device-admin

I was able to follow and complete the [Device Administration Sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).
I can successfully lock, wipe data and do other administrative tasks as well.

Case 1:
The problem I noticed is that whenever I disable the device administrator (settings->security->choose device administrators) then restart the device, the device administrator is enabled again after restart.

Case 2:
Eventhough after I installed my app and did not activate the device administrator through my app. The device administrator is still enabled after restart.

Is this a device administrator feature after restart? or limitation?
What could be wrong?
Need some help. Thanks

Comment: +1,I have added a device admin, restarted my phone, started a service, but when I unlock the screen t ask for PIN, what I set at public CharSequence onDisableRequested(Context context, Intent intent)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug in the device because there's no logical reason for that to happen. Try pulling the battery out while the phone is on, then just normally powering off and back on, and if it continues acting weird, uninstall and re-install the app, if it still happens, try a different device or do a factory data reset. Only thing I can think of.

Comment: I tried what you told me about pulling the battery and powering back on and off, reinstalling and factory reset but still I have the same result. I even tried it on a brand new device but still it has the same behavior once the device administrator is activated. Thanks

Comment: Post the code for the admin receiver class and show how your app requests admin.  You could also try to clean the project in eclipse and run it again.